# Exibir texto no plot em aplicaçao python

Tags: python, processamento-de-imagens

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que faz contagens de pessoas por video, porem ele esta exibindo a contagem pelo terminal, como faço pra exibir "Encontrado N pessoas" na tela do video? segue meu código:

```
print help_message

hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector( cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector() )


capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):

  ret, img = capture.read()
# img = cv.fromarray(img)

  found, w = hog.detectMultiScale(img, winStride=(8,8), padding=(32,32), scale=1.05)
  found_filtered = []
  for ri, r in enumerate(found):
for qi, q in enumerate(found):
  if ri != qi and inside(r, q):
    break
  else:
    found_filtered.append(r)
  draw_detections(img, found)
  draw_detections(img, found_filtered, 3)
  print ' (%d) Pessoas na imagem' %  (len(found))
  font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    cv2.putText(img,'OpenCV',(10,500), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

  cv2.imshow('TELA DE CAPTURA', img)
  ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1)
  if ch == 27:
break
capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Não vou responder porque eu não uso o OpenCV em Python (e uma resposta mereceria no mínimo um exemplo curto). Mas, você pode usar a função [`putText`](http://goo.gl/pGJCLe) pra fazer o que precisa.

Comment: Ah, achei um exemplo nesta resposta do SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34273603/2896619

Comment: Olá @gabra. Você tem toda a razão. Mas, como eu disse, eu não uso OpenCV em Python, então eu nem tenho como testar pra preparar uma resposta. De todas as formas, fique a vontade de colocar a resposta se você desejar/puder fazê-lo no meu lugar. Não tem problema mesmo. :)

Comment: Eu tinha esquecido dessa pergunta, e acabei postando uma resposta que serve nessa outra: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168383/73

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como criar um texto em uma imagem em python?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168368/como-criar-um-texto-em-uma-imagem-em-python)