# Como criar um texto em uma imagem em python?

Tags: python

Eu queria criar um texto numa imagem, com python, para mostrar uma variavel (Tanto faz o formato), Ex:
eu tenho uma imagem mostrando um A = 0, ai eu altero uma variavel, refaço a imagem e aparece A = 15, tem como eu fazer algo do tipo?

Comment: Hum... por que precisa ser uma "imagem"? Um `print` não serve? Qual é a sua intenção (seria apenas depurar o conteúdo da variável)?

Comment: Isso é para um bot de um site chamado discord. tenho um banco de dados lá para as pessoas usarem em RPG. Ele mostrando uma imagem com o perfil da pessoa seria legal, só por isso mesmo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tem várias formas de fazer. Dá pra usar o pacote [PIL (Python Image Library)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16377244/2896619), dá pra usar o pacote [matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166236/add-text-to-image-animated-with-matplotlib-artistanimation), dá pra usar o pacote [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html) e por aí vai. Também dá pra usar pacotes de criação de telas (o [PyQt](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Show%20an%20image%20using%20a%20label) me vem à mente - e se a sua intenção é construir uma interface gráfica, essa é a melhor abordagem). Enfim, vc tem muitas opções.

Apesar do [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) ser algo útil para coisas bem mais rebuscadas, eu acho a abordagem dele para a criação de imagens muito simples. Eis um exemplo de código:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def mostraVariavel(nome, valor):
    # Cria uma imagem nova (tamanho 400x200 e 3 canais RGB)
    largura = 400
    altura = 200
    imagem = np.zeros((altura, largura, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    # Preenche o fundo de amarelo
    cv2.rectangle(imagem, (0, 0), (largura, altura), (0, 255, 255), -1)

    # Desenha uma borda azul
    cv2.rectangle(imagem, (0, 0), (largura-5, altura-5), (255, 0, 0), 5)

    # Desenha o texto com a variavel em preto, no centro
    texto = '{} = {}'.format(nome, valor)

    fonte = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX
    escala = 2
    grossura = 3

    # Pega o tamanho (altura e largura) do texto em pixels
    tamanho, _ = cv2.getTextSize(texto, fonte, escala, grossura)

    # Desenha o texto no centro
    cv2.putText(imagem, texto, (int(largura / 2 - tamanho[0] / 2), int(altura / 2 + tamanho[1] / 2)), fonte, escala, (0, 0, 0), grossura)

    # Exibe a imagem
    cv2.imshow("Imagem", imagem)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 15
    mostraVariavel('a', a)
```

Que produz o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Teria como usar uma imagem de fundo?

Comment: @EzequielTavares Tem sim. Abre a imagem ao invés de criar uma. A documentação do OpenCV tá cheia de exemplos de como abrir uma imagem.